# Update Mongo Subdocument Given Subdocument Criteria

Tags: mongodb

Given the following collection of items:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : "0",
    "itemName" : "item1",
    "person" : 
    {
        "name" : "a"
    }
}
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "itemName" : "item2",
    "person" : 
    {
        "name" : "a"
    }
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "itemName" : "item3",
    "person" : 
    {
        "name" : "b"
    }
}
```

How do I update persons named "a" to "a2"?

This doesn't work:

```
db.items.update(
    { "person.name" : "a" },
    { $set :{ "person.name" :"a2"} }
)
```

**UPDATE**
Actually, the above *does* work, but it only works for the first record.  Passing the multi parameter to this updates them all.

And this gives me the error "uncaught exception: can't have . in field names [person.name]"

```
db.items.update(
    { "person.name" : "a" },
    { "person.name" : "a2"}
)
```

Comment: It appears that the structure of your collection is wrong. Or at least the way you are querying it. What do you see when you run `db.person.findOne()`?

Comment: sorry, typo when typing data by hand, updated the question

Comment: @dev It's still not right, you're showing one document with multiple fields named "_id" and "person".

Comment: There is still a problem with the schema you're showing. You have duplicate fields and duplicate values for `_id`, which need to be unique. Could you add what you see when you run the command `db.person.findOne();` from the `mongo` shell? That would give a better idea of what your documents look like in the person collection.  Or have a look at my answer below.

Comment: sorry, i'm generating this data by hand.  how does it look now?  there should be three documents (called item) and each one has a person record inside of it

Comment: @dev Based on your latest update, the code that follows "This doesn't work" is correct, but you'd want to add the `{multi: true}` option to the call so that it applies to all matched docs instead of just the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the updated information you provided, if the documents in your items collection look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "0",
    "itemName" : "item1",
    "person" : 
    {
        "name" : "a"
    }
}
```

Then you can update the name of all persons named "a" to name "b" by running:

```
db.items.update({ "person.name" : "a" }, { "$set" : { "person.name" : "b" } }, { "multi" : true });
```

This will match all people with the value "a" in the `name` field, set the field's value to "b" and apply it to all documents by setting the `multi` option to `true`. Otherwise, only the first match will be updated.

The command `db.items.update({ "person.name" : "a" }, { "person.name" : "a2"} );` gives you an error because with that syntax, what `update()` does is replaces the whole of the matching document with the document specified as the second parameter. Hence it rejects this update thinking that you want to replace the document with a document containing the field `person.name` with the value "a2".